# Reduce required space for Windows 8 recovery partition

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, sony-vaio, recovery-partition

I want to make a copy of the restore partition on Windows to an external flash drive. I have a 16 GB flash drive but using the Windows Restore disk transfer tool it says that it needs 26 GB of storage to transfer. The VAIO recovery tool says 18GB.

How do I make it go under 16? I remember the number was below 10 previously.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mess with system recovery partitions.. is it worth the hassle? It would be much simpler to use the VAIO recovery disk application to burn the recovery partition to a bootable set of DVDs (or USB if it lets you) so you can restore in the future. Once you've got a set of disks THEN you can safely delete the partition. To restore simply boot off the DVDs...

Comment: But looks like it is including either user installed apps or only metro apps. if that is the case, then i can uninstall those apps and make the disk

Comment: Did your laptop come with the ability to write the "factory image" to a USB or DVD?

Have a search in Windows 8 for "VAIO Recovery Center". If you do have a recovery application it should allow you to make a complete recovery backup of the factory image...

Comment: Yes. Sony and microsoft both have their own tools for it. The sony ones required around 8-12 GB befor but now wants 18 GB. I want to know how that 4 GB increase came from and how to go back to 12GB.